# Creating and connecting to a new database

Tags: c#, sql-server

My application successfully creates a new database utilising the following string:

```
SqlString = $"CREATE DATABASE {_databaseName} ON PRIMARY " +
$"(NAME = {_databaseName}_Data, " +
$"FILENAME = '{_filePath}', " +
"SIZE = 8192KB, MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 10%) " +
$"LOG ON (NAME = {_databaseName}_Log, " +
$"FILENAME = '{_databasePathLdf}', " +
"SIZE = 8192KB, " +
"MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, " +
"FILEGROWTH = 10%)";
ExecuteSqlQuery(@"server=.\SQLEXPRESS; Trusted_Connection = Yes", SqlString);
```

When I then try to reconnect to the database use the following connection string

```
internal string ConnectionString(String databaseName)
{
    return  $"Server =.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database={databaseName};Trusted_Connection=Yes;";
}
```

I get the following error

[image: Error Message]

For clarity the connection strings both use `Trusted_Connection = Yes` and the owner and login are the same when creating and connecting to the database.

For further clarity I am utilising OpenFileDialog to navigate to the database to connect utilising the following:

```
internal string OpenFileDialog(String initialDirectory)
    {
        string filePath = "";
        using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = initialDirectory;
            openFileDialog.Filter = "mdf Database file (*.mdf)|*.mdf";
            openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;
            if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;
            }
        }
        return filePath;
    }
```

The error occurs on the DialogResult.OK.

How can you utilise OpenFileDialog in this instance to return the file path of the database to connect to?

I am using SQL Server Express 2019 (v15.0.2070).

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: *"My application successfully create a new server utilising the following string"* That creates a database, *not* a server. Express is the server (instance), which you will have installed. As for the error, I doubt that that connection string will have cause it. You don't "open" a database file; it is attached to an instance, and then you send SQL Commands to that instance to query said database.

Comment: Thank you for you prompt response and correcting my error It should read Database not Server. I don't understand however why I get the error "You don't have permission" when I try to open the connection to the database.

Comment: Integrated Security uses a windows credential.  So it should be using the same user account that you are using to login.  I would use SQL Server Management Studio and check the Server to make sure you have access.  On the login GUI make sure you set the dropdown for Windows Credential.  Then check to see if you have access to the database.  Use the Explorer in SSMS to check access and you can make queries to test that you can read the database/tables.

Comment: Thank you for your response. SQL Server Management Studio confirms Windows Authentication, the username is the same as the login and I can confirm access to the database. This only makes it more confusing why I receive the error when I utilise Trusted Connection to connect to the database within my application.

Comment: Does server have more than one database.  The default database may be wrong.  In your query you can add to the beginning : "Use DataBase;" or add the default database to the connection string.  Also check the server/instance on the SSMS login window and make sure you connection string matches.

Comment: Thankyou for all your feedback it has allowed me to narrow down the problem to the fact that I am utilising OpenFileDialog to navigate to the file path of the database to be connected too, and it is this that is creating the error. I am now unsure how to utilise OpenFileDialog to get the database name and path without it thronging the error.

Comment: Just because a Sql Server login has permissions to create new databases, it doesn't automatically mean the login has permissions to use or connect to any database it creates. That is managed separately.

Comment: A thing that immediatly smells like a problem is the fact that you use an open file dialog to select a database. When you use SQL Server (or any other DB server for the matter) you don't manage the DB files, the DB engine does. In fact, they're not even located in your computer, but in the DB server filesystem. Why do you care about the mdf files at all?

Comment: Thank you for your response. The reason why I am utilising the open file dialog is that the application needs to be able to switch between different databases and the name of the databases is not pre set. I have just found that utilising OpenFileDialog.ValidateNames = false; results in no error and the application works as expected. Unsure if this is the right way to go though?

Comment: No, it's not. The users should not browser through the SQL server data directory to browse databases. The app should connect to the SQL server and fetch a list of available databases.